# Is it possible to have a custom domain and no port number for GitLab in Synology?

Tags: docker, gitlab, nas, synology

So, I got this Synology NAS running DSM 6.1, and among the apps I can install is GitLab (AWESOME), which I have installed, but to access it I have to go through the URL for DS plus the port number.  I would like access it the way access other apps, via a subdomain.  For example, my DS is at [https://ds.mydomain.com] and to get to gitlab I am going through [https://ds.mydomain.com:30001], but what I want to is to access it like this [https://gitlab.mydomain.com] with a subdomain and no port number.

So far, I've setup the subdomain which does redirect to it and I've acquired the SSL cert.  But I still can't get rid off the port from URL  [https://gitlab.mydomain.com:XXXXX]

The Synology NAS allows you to use custom domains for a lot of their apps.  For example, for the video station, I can access it via a custom folder [https://ds.mydomain.com:XXXX/video] (XXXX is the port number) or a custom subdomain [https://video.mydomain.com].
I am partial to the subdomains because of the cleaner URLS, and I would like to setup GitLab to be the same way.  But I can't figure out how to do it. I've got the subdomain working [https://gitlab.mydomain.com].

Is there a setting in DSM or during the package installation that will allow me to do this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I know its old question but maybe this link will help you (or others) :) https://blog.golimb.com/2017/07/14/synology-reverse-proxy/